# How to Install Ruby gems on all agents using TeamCity?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, teamcity, watir

I am working on Teamcity 6.5.6, and looking for a way to automatically install required ruby GEMS on build agents. 
For Ex: Suppose I have two gems that are required on each agent/remote (build) machine. Ex: Watir and Selenium gems. Then am I suppose to install them manually by logging on to those machines, or can I do keep them in a common library folder in SVN, and perform some tasks in Teamcity to install them if not present on machine. 
If so, then What would be that task in Teamcity?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

You could maintain a list of your required gems in a Gemfile, then run `bundle install` on each machine before the build starts. This would install all of the gems in the Gemfile (and you could lock gems to a particular version by also including the Gemfile.lock file).

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you have idea, can you please tell me if this can be done from RAKE task in teamcity (I am just a week old in this)?

Comment: Yeah you could write a rake task to run the `bundle install` command/